# Inverse image of $x^2+1$

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

$$f(x) = x^2+1$$

$$E = (-1,2]$$

$$f(E)= (1,5]$$

for the inverse image:

$$ -1 \lt x^2+1 \leq 2$$

$$-2 \lt x^2 \leq 1$$

taking the square root gives me an imaginary number the back of the book says that the answer is (-1,1)

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say $[-1,1]$?

Comment: yes the final image for $f^{-1}$ is in fact said to be $[-1,1]$ but I cant get there i am stuck between -2 and 1

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the direct image is wrong, it is not $(1,5]$ but $[1,5]$. Note $f(0)=1$ so $1$ also belongs to the image.

As for the inverse image: you know that $x^2\ge 0$ anyways, so the condition is actually $0\le x^2\le 1$, i.e. $x\in[-1,1]$. Thus the inverse image is $[-1, 1]$. (I don't know why your book claims that it is $(-1,1)$, obviously $f(\pm 1)=2\in (-1,2]$.)

Advice: it would help if you could draw the graph of $f(x)=x^2+1$, and then look up:

- What the interval $(-1,2]$ (on the $x$ axis) maps to, and
- What maps into the interval $(-1, 2]$ (on the $y$ axis).

Answer (score 0):

You also know that $x^2\ge 0$, so you should write $0\le x^2\le 1$. Taking the square root is not enough, since $(-x)^2=x^2$. So if a positive $x$ satisfies the condition, so will $-x$. So if you take square toot, you get $$0\le x\le 1$$**OR**
$$0\ge x\ge -1$$
Putting it all together, you get $$-1\le x \le 1$$

Comment: what happened to the +1?